# Open story page of instagram to share image or video

Tags: java, android

I want to share my image into instagram story. Now I can open istagram easily like this , but this code show me the page that we share photo.
I dont want this one, I want to open instagram story page just.

Here with this code:

```
try {
 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 File media = new File(path);
 Uri screenshotUri = Uri.fromFile(media);
 sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
 sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
 sharingIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
 startActivity(sharingIntent);
} catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(SavedActivity.this, "برنامه اینستاگرام یافت نشد.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Is it possible to share directly into story of instagram?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible (not to mention bad practice).

You can only dictate which application(s) can handle your intent, not what they do with that intent once it is received.

It is also not good practice to hardcode the application package you want to send to within your codebase (i.e. `"com.instagram.android"`). The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser) as well as the [Instagram developers documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/) recommends that you use the standard "chooser" pattern to share photos. In which case, the user will decide which app to share the photo with.

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType(type);

File media = new File(mediaPath);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No application to share with", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Unless this is a personal project (it will not make it to the Google Play Store), I suggest you stick to the above pattern.

Comment: I know that , just I want to know that Is it possible to open instagram story directly?

Comment: @user7908469 Not unless Instagram has implemented something on their end to make this possible, and based on what I have read from their documentation, they haven't. Though, now that I think of it, they may have implemented [deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html), in which case you should be able to use the URL to the story in an `ACTION_VIEW` intent; and that would link to the story in the app (if it is installed).

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(dest));
    sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
    sharingIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share Video "));
```

I hope it helps someone .